# Get Raspi's CPU temperature within Docker container

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, raspberry-pi

I've build a little ASP.NET Core application for my Raspberry Pi 4 which lets me control a fan ([see here](https://github.com/mu88/RaspiFanController/)). The app is deployed as a small self-contained Linux application running on bare metal of my Raspi.

For measuring the temperature, I'm calling `vcgencmd measure_temp` on the Raspi which gives me the actual temperature.

For various reasons, I'd prefer to run this app within a Docker container:

- No more manual service registration within Linux, Docker feature `--restart-always` handles this.
- No more downloading the latest release from GitHub, extracting and marking the app as executable.

But I have no clue how I can retrieve the Raspi's temperature from within a container.

I already tried to map the Raspi's directory `/usr/bin/` into a Docker container and call `vcgencmd` from inside - but that simply fails due to missing dependencies.
And I already found an answer on Stack Overflow suggesting to create a named pipe on the Raspi and then consume this pipe from within the container. But this removes the beauty of a container if I have to setup something like a named pipe.

So long story short: is there any way to get the Raspi's current CPU temperature from within a Docker container?

Thx!

Comment: Can you explain the reasons why you want to have a Docker container when it has such a strong dependency on the host?

Comment: I've added my motivation to the question

Comment: Someone from the Linux world helped me - you can find the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/706181/529445).

Answer (score 0):

Create a volume to `/opt/vc/bin/` and run the `./vcgencmd` program using .NET's Process builder API's

Comment: The volume is empty and therefore results in `./vcgenmod: No such file or directory`